# Folder permissions script exceeding the time allocated for execution

Tags: powershell, directory, powershell-4.0

I have a simple PowerShell v4 script that pulls directory permissions on a hard drive and writes them to a file.

It runs fine 90% of the time, but other times my output file is empty or only partially full. The error log says the "task was terminated due to exceeding the time allocated for execution" which is 1 hour. Normally this task runs in 5 minutes.

Any ideas about what might be causing this and a solution?

```
$RootPath = "D:"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }

    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
        if ($Folder.fullname -NotMatch "superoldhome"){
            $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "`t" + $ACL.IdentityReference + "`t" + $ACL.AccessControlType 
            Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile      
        }
    }}
```

Comment: We can't debug for you. We don't have access to your environment. It might not have anything to do with the script. You could add some built in logging (which you partially have) to try and track progress. Script does not appear to have any error handling either.

Comment: I would use dumpsec instead (no sense in reinventing the wheel).

Answer (score 0):

Is this running as a Windows task? Maybe it is losing access to the hard drive for some reason? If you really want to use this, I would suggest a few debug lines to make sure it stays connected . Maybe something like:

```
if (Test-Path $Folder) {}
else {Add-Content -Value "Unable to resolve Path" -Path $OutFile}
```

If you have that in your loop if that is the problem itll write to the log. Or you can log everything to a file that happens. I forget how to do that off the top of my head, but let me know, I can probably dig that up.

Comment: I personally think this is not a good answer as it asks more question than it answers, it isn't well formatted and provides an uncomplete code example. It would be better as a comment suggesting error handling like @Matt did one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the feedback.
I am experimenting with dumpsec and have high hopes for that.
If it doesn't get me what I want I will try adding some more logging like Matt & Kenny suggested.